# Using socat for raw serial connection

Tags: linux, bash, serial-port, socat

The goal is to connect to an `embedded` device using `serial` interface.
So far, I've used:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS2 115200 cs8 ixoff
socat readline,history=/etc/socat.history /dev/ttyS2,raw,echo=0
```

And it works excellent, but then I discovered that there are some options during `system boot` that require you to press a single key without pressing `enter`, and `readline` fails there. So my idea was to bind the `ttyS2` to `cons0`, but then I discovered multiple problems, such as inability to quit (`ctr+c`, `ctr+q` `ctr+]` and even `esc` doesn't work), `backspace` and `delete` do not work, letters are typed twice, etc. So after some trial and error, I came up with this:

```
socat /dev/cons0,raw,echo=0,crnl /dev/ttyS2,raw,echo=0,escape=0x03,crnl
```

- `raw` on both sides allows a single `key press` to trigger a `boot option`
- `echo=0` on both sides prevents `key press` doubling
- `crnl` on both sides prevent `enter` `key press` doubling
- `escape=0x03` allows me to `quit` the thing by pressing `ctr+c`

The problem is, when I quit, my `cons0` is all f****d up, as if it somehow preserved the `raw,echo=0,crnl` settings. I know this problem is probably too specific for my scenario, but I just need a simple way to send keystrokes to serial as I would with `putty` (which is not available on my platform). I am using `socat` because it is extremely lightweight, does not require any aditional libraries, and because the shown commands are a part of the greater script that uses `expect`.

Any ideas and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use `reset` or `stty sane` after the `socat` command to reset the terminal to sane values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Austin Phillips says, you can use `stty sane` to recover...

...but what is even better is that you can (probably) append it to your socat command as `socat xxxxx ; stty sane` and have the recovery be *automatic* when you quit with ctrl-c.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, that worked for me!
I just want to point out that the script should not rely on "static" console identification, because when `expect` spawns the script, it is going to have a completely different `tty`, therefor:

```
socat $(tty),raw,echo=0,escape=0x03 /dev/ttyS2,raw,echo=0,nonblock ; stty sane
```

edit: `nonblock` also solved the "enter" problem

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, there are more native mechanisms for socat...

`socat STDIO,raw,echo=0,crnl /dev/ttyUSB1,sane,rawer,b115200,cs8,parenb=0; stty sane`

In this configuration, socat will natively set the baud rate and the various tty parameters.  Note that "rawer" is a combination of "raw" and "echo=0" and maybe other undocumented things--it also supports cfmakeraw.

Note that you probably still want to do `stty sane` after socat exits to solve this actual questions as the other answers suggest.  While socat will try to restore the STDIO tty settings, not all killing methods will allow this to run (e.g. kill -9). However, this approach is better than trying to run `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB1` *before* running socat--sometimes those terminal settings get lost.

I stumbled on this question when I was having massive problems with minicom dropping characters (the serial line did not support any flow control).  I switched to socat (with the internal termio settings) and the problem went away--presumably because socat is so much more lightweight. (I also eventually discovered, after many many years of using it, that screen has native serial terminal support, which gave me the ability to do emacs, ^C, and other tty-aware commands, and it too didn't drop characters, so maybe this minicom version is just stupid).