# gdb No such file or directory error

Tags: gdb, arm, gdbserver

***Update: found a workaround - explained at the bottom***

I'm trying to remote debug my program via a serial port.
On the target machine (arm, linux) (connected to host machine (Windows) via serial-to-usb) I connected via [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/) and looked for `ttyS*` in `/dev` directory, but I don't have any. I have only `tty[num]` (without the `S`), and running:

```
dmesg | grep tty
```

as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125261) gives the following:

```
# dmesg | grep tty
Kernel command line: mxc_hdmi.only_cea=0 console=ttymxc1,115200 vmalloc=400M consoleblank=0 rootwait fixrtc root=/dev/mmcblk1p1
2020000.serial: ttymxc0 at MMIO 0x2020000 (irq = 58, base_baud = 5000000) is a IMX
21e8000.serial: ttymxc1 at MMIO 0x21e8000 (irq = 59, base_baud = 5000000) is a IMX
console [ttymxc1] enabled
```

So I tried to use `ttymxc0` and `ttymxc1`:

```
gdbserver /dev/ttymxc0 ./test/main
Process ./test/main created; pid = 253
Remote debugging using /dev/ttymxc0
```

and on host machine (Windows 7): *(edited following comments)*

```
gdb path/on/host/main
(gdb) target remote COM15
COM15: No such file or directory.
```

I see [here](https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2007-11/msg00006.html) that serial was broken at **gdb 6.6**, but I have **gdb 7.7**.

Why am I getting the **No such file or directory** error?

---

**edit 2:**

Although I had tried renaming the port to **COM5** and it didn't help (same result), I renamed the port to **COM2** and it worked for once and then it got out and stopped working:

```
(gdb) target remote COM2
Remote debugging using COM2
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
Malformed response to offset query, qOffsets //got out
(gdb) target remote COM2 //tried again, didn't work
COM2: No such file or directory.
```

The difference between **COM2** and **COM15** (besides the digits number) is that
in Windows Device Manager **COM2** appeared as "used", and **COM15** (and **COM5**) did not. When I picked **COM2** as the new name, Windows warned me that it's being used but I accepted the change anyway.

Now I [cleared all COM ports](https://superuser.com/questions/408976/how-do-i-clean-up-com-ports-in-use) and now it's working alternately (haven't succeeded actually debugging yet, but it's not falling on that "no such file or directory" error anymore).

**edit 3:**

So now `target remote COM2` responds with "Remote debugging using COM2 , Malformed response..." when I'm **not** connected to the target via Putty. When I am connected via Putty, it says "COM2: No such file or directory". It's like the port is taken (by Putty) and gdb can't log into it.

---

I ended up connecting by TCP instead of serial line:

- Connect target to internet by ethernet cable
- edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to setup dhcp:

> auto eth0
>
> iface eth0 inet dhcp

- run `ifconfig` or `ip addr` on target to get the ip
- run on target:

`gdbserver [ip:port] ./path/to/executable/on/target`

- run on host:

`gdb path/to/executable/on/host/compiled/to/target`

`(gdb) target remote [target's ip:port]`

This is a sufficient workaround for me.

Comment: Presumably the host machine and target machine are not identical, therefore why would you expect them to have identical serial ports?

Comment: I thought I need to provide the host machine with the port name in the target machine. But I also tried `(gdb) target remote COM15` (`COM15` is the port name in the host machine) and got the same result

Comment: Ah, GNU tools on Windows, that explains a lot ;) The problem will be that [you're using COM15, and GDB is not clever enough to do the right thing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#win32_device_namespaces).

Comment: I see. So the problem exists in `COM[num], num>9`. I tried `\\.\COM15` as the post suggests, and got the same result. I also tried changing the port name to `COM2`, and then `target remote COM2` => same result.

Comment: It could be a .config file problem, try to see your settings in this file /proc/config.gz (this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelDebuggingTricks, for example in serial console section)

Comment: Try `target remote /dev/ttyS14` to use COM15. Also, you may need to adjust the serial port's speed to match that of the target (`set serial baud nnnnn` on the gdb side).

Comment: @invictus1306 But the problem seems to be in the host machine, so why edit files in the target machine?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick We are talking Windows...Why would COM15 be called **/dev/ttyS14** ?

Comment: @AlaaM. That's the notation that Cygwin-compiled programs use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899180/how-can-i-use-com-and-usb-ports-within-cygwin

Comment: @MarkPlotnick So `COM[x]` = `ttyS[x-1]` ? Anyway it's not working... Same result. And I'm using linaro cross compiler. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @AlaaM I think for this reason: tty[num] (without the S)

Comment: Yes, COM[x] = ttyS[x-1]. The compiler that produces binaries that you run on the remote system won't affect the naming convention used by gdb to access the local system's serial ports.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick OK I tried. Connecting to and disconnecting from it works via Hype!Terminal (but only when I'm not connected to it by Putty). I need to connect to it by Putty to run `gdbserver ...`. Anyway, `(gdb) target remote COM15` doesn't work in Windows cmd also when I'm not connected to the port via Putty (neither does `target remote /dev/ttyS14`)